# Disable letter in text input php using android webview

Tags: android

I develop a website in php and it include username and password. where user can type their student id, In default browser its totally working and fine and the student can't type letter in the username. But when i apply it in android studio  webview, It allow letter to type when i apply it in webview. Help me to resolve my problem because i am new in android studio.

//login_view.class

```
    String url=    "http://uopcereviewer.16mb.com/CE%20Reviewer/php/student/login.php";user_name" + name;
    final WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);


  // final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(login_view.this, " ",  "Loading ...", true);


    view.getSettings();
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    view.loadUrl(url);
    view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

    });

    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    WebSettings setting = view.getSettings();

    setting.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = sharedPreferences.getString("idnum", DEFAULT);

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        //  public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        //progress.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        // }
    });

    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view1, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            view1.loadUrl("about:blank");
            Toast.makeText(login_view.this, "Error Check your Internet Connection..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view1, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            //  pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view1, String url) {
            //    pd.dismiss();
            String webUrl = view.getUrl();
        }

    });
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("MyData",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String name= sharedPreferences.getString("idnum",DEFAULT);

    view.loadUrl("http://uopcereviewer.16mb.com/CE%20Reviewer/php/student/login.php?StudentNumber=sharedpref &Password=sharedpref Password" + name);

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    return;
}
```

}